# How to get soft deleted records along with its soft deleted relational records using Laravel5

Tags: laravel-5, soft-delete

How can i get all soft deleted records along with its related table records which are also soft deleted?

I am able to get all soft deleted records by this

```
Posts::with('wihslists')->onlyTrashed()->orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
```

This return me list of soft deleted posts,but does not return its related wishlists?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following code though I didn't test it.

```
Posts::with(['wihslists' => function ($query) {
    $query->onlyTrashed();
}])
->onlyTrashed()
->orderBy('id','DESC')
->get();
```